# How to use a fast_strtime() in a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

I need help to use fast_strptime in a data.table to convert a string in a date format,
I have tried following solutions:

```
dt<-data.table(Month_Year=c("JAN 2020","FEB 2020", "MAR 2020"), val=c(1:3))
dt[,Date:=as.POSIXct(fast_strptime(Month_Year,format= "%^b %Y"))]
dt$Date<-fast_strptime(dt$Month_Year, format="%b %Y")
```

None of them work, I appriciate any help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what package is it? `'fast_strptime' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'`

Comment: It's maybe from lubridate? It doesn't seem to be a vectorized function...

Comment: correct it ist a function of lubridate package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine

```
dt[,Date:=as.POSIXct(lubridate::fast_strptime(Month_Year, "%b %Y"))]
```

The issue is that `fast_strptime()` produces a POSIXlt object rather than a POSIXct one. POSIXlt is basically a list of integers and so data.table gets confused, whereas POSIXct is a single numeric value.

I'd probably use `parse_date_time` though

```
dt[,Date:=lubridate::parse_date_time(Month_Year, "my")]
```

Comment: could you explain what happened there? why as.POSIXct saves the day and transforms a 9 element vector (output from lubridate::fast_strptime(Month_Year, "%b %Y")) into a 3 one?

Comment: I got following warning: **Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.**

Comment: What does this warning means?

Comment: @Irina that's something to do with repeatedly overwriting columns with different types. If you start over and just create the `dt` table and then run the line in my answer it should disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a work around, not with fast_strptime() function, but it fits my expectations for now:

```
dt[,Date:=as.Date(paste("01",Month_Year, sep=" "),format = "%d %b %Y")]
```

I hope it helps others, who face the same issue.

But I am still intressted in how to use fast_striptime in combination with data.table. :)